# How do I grab the first objects from a Django queryset?

Tags: django

```
execution_list = JobExecution.objects.filter(job__name=job_name).order_by('-build_id')[:50]
last = execution_list.pop(1)
print last.id
```

I've also tried execution_list[0], which throws another queryset error.

How do I i just grab the first object from the queryset?  I am aware that I can just append .last() to the query, but the problem is I need the full list as well as the first item.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
Error: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#first)

For example

```
JobExecution.objects.filter(job__name=job_name).order_by('-build_id').first()
```

will return the JobExecution object with the largest `build_id`

Note that you can't slice and then also grab the `.first()` because this doesn't convert nicely into SQL, but you can do something like

```
queryset = JobExecution.objects.filter(job__name=job_name).order_by('-build_id')
first_50 = queryset[:50] # this will not evaluate the queryset
first = queryset.first() # this will evaluate the queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

Even when you slice `[:50]`, it still returns a QuerySet rather than a list. You could say `last = list(execution_list)[0]`, which would give you just the first element. Be aware that this would also execute the query immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the queryset to a list and then pop the last item.

```
execution_list = list(JobExecution.objects.filter(job__name=job_name).order_by('-build_id')[:50])
last = execution_list.pop(0)
```

Note that I’ve used `pop(0)` to get the first item from the list - `pop(1)` would pop the second item from the list because lists are zero-indexed.